# Open application in separate console window

Tags: c++, linux, gnome-terminal

I'm currently writing an application that I would like to open in a new terminal window, resizing it in the process, rather than the one in which the invoking command was typed. How should I go about doing this? I'm using the gnome terminal and will be writing the app in C++.

Comment: There are [hordes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_terminal_emulators#X_Window_Terminals) of terminal emulators running under linux. Which one do you want to spawn? Using which language?

Comment: I've updated the question with the additional information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `gnome-terminal --geometry="20x10" -e 'command'` (20 is height, 10 is width).

In C++, you can call a command by using [system()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system).

Answer (score 2):

There is no pure C++ way to do this. What you are wanting to do is inherently system dependent, so you have to use *system()* defined in cstdlib.

You can call this as:

```
    system("<your-shell-command> <parameters>");
```

For e.g.,

```
    system("/usr/bin/gnome-terminal /usr/executables/a.out");
```

or

```
    system("C:\\Windows\\cmd.exe C:\\Users\FuUser\\Binaries\a.exe");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this from the Linux console you want `openvt`:

http://www.oreillynet.com/linux/cmd/cmd.csp?path=o/openvt

If you are talking about a terminal window under X you can usually use a command like

```
gnome-terminal -e "command"
```